# short code are not working on my custom theme

Tags: wordpress

i am not able to use any shortcode in my custom them is there any thing need to add in functions.php to enable shortcode feature??

i have created simple shortcode like in funxtions.php

```
function custom_shortcode(){
 echo "hello there !!!";
}

add_shortcode('mycode', 'custom_shortcode');
```

but when i am trying to use my short code in post it shows simple [mycode] as display output

i dont know whats wrong in that i think i am missing to add something in functions.php for shortcode feature in my cutom theme

Comment: Your shortcode might be preformatted by wordpress' Visual editor. View your shortcode in Text mode remove unnecessary tags if exists.

Comment: i have checked short code in both section text and visual both but still it simply disply [mycode] as output

Comment: How is your post template displaying `post_content`? Can you edit your question and show the code for that part of your post template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing you just need replace "echo" by "return", so:

```
function custom_shortcode(){
    return "hello there !!!";
}
add_shortcode('mycode', 'custom_shortcode');
```

"Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce output of any kind. Shortcode functions should return the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode. Producing the output directly will lead to unexpected results. This is similar to the way filter functions should behave, in that they should not produce expected side effects from the call, since you cannot control when and where they are called from."

From: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode